# Transcript a C bitwise operation to JS

Tags: javascript, c, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

I'm trying to transcript the following C code to JavaScript, but I'm not getting it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

long long seed;
int next(int bits) {
 seed=(seed * 0x5DEECE66DL + 0xBL) & ((1L << 48) - 1);
 return (int)(seed >> (48 - bits));
}

void main (void) {
    seed = 0;
    for (int i=0;i<20;i++) {
        printf ("%d\n", next(31));
    }
}
```

This was my try but I got different results from the C code:

```js
let seed;
function next(bits) {
 seed = (seed * 0x5DEECE66D + 0xB) & ((1 << 48) - 1);
 return (seed >> (48 - bits));
}

seed = 0;
for ( let i=0; i<20; i++ ) {
    console.log( next(31) );
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: JavaScript bit manipulation is done on 32 bits. You'll have to separate the number out somehow. Try `console.log((1 << 48).toString(16))` and you'll see the issue.

Comment: What value are you passing for `bits`?

Comment: An Integer between 1 and 32

Comment: What is `seed`? What type is it? Your shift is between 16 and 47 bits.

Comment: Thanks, so for `long long` the numeric type should be `1LL` not `1L`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use BigInt in javascript with BigInt() and n appended to the number literals:

```
let seed = 0n;

function next(bits) {
  seed = (seed * BigInt(0x5deece66d) + BigInt(0xb)) & ((1n << 48n) - 1n);
  return seed >> (48n - bits);
}

for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  console.log(next(31n));
}
```

Output:

```
0n
2116118n
89401895n
379337186n
782977366n
196130996n
198207689n
1046291021n
1131187612n
975888346n
500746873n
1785185521n
2000878121n
1219898729n
1194203485n
109160704n
1647229822n
40619231n
541938462n
640373553n
```